# For each row in matrix1 and each row in matrix2 do difference element-wise

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Hello I'd like to ask for a more performance efficient solution for this problem: given two matrices: one with shape (60000, 748) and second with shape (10000, 748) I'd like to iterate over each row in first matrix and for each row in second matrix. Next I'd like to subtract the rows and sum the differences and save them in a "result" matrix. My primitive version is given below.

```
val = np.array([[0, 2, 4, 2], [2, 4, 1, 5], [3, 3, 1, 9]])
val2 = np.array([[7, 3, 6, 8], [2, 1, 6, 2]])

result = np.zeros((val.shape[0], val2.shape[0]))
for outer_index, validated in enumerate(val):
    for inner_index, trained in enumerate(val2):
        print(np.absolute(validated - trained).sum(0))
        result[outer_index][inner_index] = np.absolute(validated - trained).sum(0)
return result
```

Comment: Can you please add some example matrices we can try it on? They don't need to be the full size you intend to use in the end, a 2x3 and 2x4 would be plenty, and we'd have a 3x4 output matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new axis to the first vector, making it in
shape `(val.shape[0], 1, val.shape[1])` while the second vector is in its original shape and as long as `val.shape[1]` and `val2.shape[1]` are equal the 2 vectors are broadcastable.
Use this code:

```
def diff(val, val2):
    return np.abs(val[:,np.newaxis] - val2).sum(2)
```

Try this than, which is looping on the smaller vector (not using much more memory):

```
def diff(val, val2):
    if val.shape[0] < val2.shape[0]:
        val2, val = val, val2
    smaller_vec_size = val2.shape[0]
    bigger_vec_size = val.shape[0]
    k = np.empty((smaller_vec_size,bigger_vec_size))
    for i in range(smaller_vec_size):
        k[i] = np.abs(val - val2[i]).sum(1)
    return k
```

Comment: I tried it but it results in (10000, 60000, 784) shaped array. I want to have a result in (10000, 60000) shape.

Comment: Are you sure? sum(2) should cancel the last dimension and making the sum of that.
It worked for me on your toy example.

Comment: Oh, the problem is that the matrix is too large to be in a memory as a (10000, 60000, 784) shape for even a split second so the sum(2) doesn't have a chance to reduce the last dimension.